# SPARQL Update (DELETE/INSERT) with WHERE Condition Referencing Multiple Graphs

Tags: sparql, rdf, fuseki

I'm trying to do a SPARQL update in Jena Fuseki, but I can't seem to get it to work.

The following is the issue:

I have triples in a graph (named `freetest`), and those triples need to be changed.
And in a separate graph (named `knora-base`), I have a "ontology" describing the data in the first graph.

In order to identify the triples that need updating, I need information from the ontology.

In a SELECT query, this works perfectly fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest>
FROM <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base>
WHERE {
    ?s ?p ?o.
    ?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> 'b' .
    ?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#Value> .
    ?s a ?def
}
LIMIT 25
```

The two FROM clauses make the WHERE block act on a union of the two graphs, so that I can check if `hasPermission` equals `'b'`, which is a triple in the data graph (`freetest`), as well as that the resource at hand is of type `?def` (again in the data graph), which must be a `<subClassOf>*` of `Value` (which is defined in the ontology graph).

As mentioned, this works as expected.

However I don't get it to work to update those triples. Among many variations, I tried:

```
DELETE { GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest> 
    {?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?perm}
}
INSERT { GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest> 
    {?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?new}
}
USING <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base>
USING <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest>
WHERE {
    VALUES ?perm {'b'}
    VALUES ?new {'c'}
    ?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?perm .    
    ?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#Resource> .
    ?s a ?def
}
```

I expected this to have the same behaviour as the SELECT query above, with multiple USING statements giving me access to multiple graphs in the WHERE clause.

However this doesn't update any triples in the database.

Note though, that when I remove the line `?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#Resource> .` it does update the triples. But obviously without the restriction I wanted, so too many triples get updated.

I'm sure I'm just not fully understanding named graphs, sparql update, USING, or all of them. But I also can't find much information on the topic. (While named graphs in SELECT seem to be covered by quite a number of very informative articles.)

---

**Update 1:**

According to the comments, I also tried to explicitly define the graph in the WHERE clause:

```
WITH <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest>
DELETE { GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest> 
    {?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?perm}
}
INSERT { GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/data/0001/freetest> 
    {?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?new}
}
WHERE {
    VALUES ?perm {'c'}
    VALUES ?new {'d'}
    ?s <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#hasPermissions> ?perm .
    GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base> {
        ?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#Resource> .
    }
    ?s a ?def
}
```

This did not change the observed behaviour.

---

**Update 2:**

I tried to reproduce it with a simple sample, so I did the following:

1. Use my regular Fuseki Setup
2. Send a `DROP ALL` to have the same settings but no triples
3. Upload a simple dataset:

```
@prefix a: <http://test.org/a#> .
@prefix b: <http://test.org/b#> .
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl:         <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .

a:A {
    a:Resource 
        a owl:Class ;
        rdfs:label "Resource"@en .

    a:Value 
        a owl:Class ;
        rdfs:label "Value"@en .

    a:SubResource 
        a owl:Class ;
        rdfs:subClassOf a:Resource ;
        rdfs:label "Sub-Resource"@en .
}

b:B {
    b:ResourceInstance 
        a a:Resource ;
        b:hasValue "a".

    b:ValueInstance 
        a a:Value ;
        b:hasValue "a".

    b:SubResourceInstance 
        a a:SubResource ;
        b:hasValue "a".
}
```

In this, `a:` is the ontology and `b:` is the data.

Then I sent the following update:

```
WITH <http://test.org/b#B>
DELETE { 
    ?s <http://test.org/b#hasValue> ?oldVal
}
INSERT {
    ?s <http://test.org/b#hasValue> ?newVal
}
USING <http://test.org/a#A>
USING <http://test.org/b#B>
WHERE {
    VALUES ?oldVal {'a'}
    VALUES ?newVal {'b'}
    ?s <http://test.org/b#hasValue> ?oldVal .
    ?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://test.org/a#Resource> .
    ?s a ?def
}
```

This produced the expected result: The values in `b:ResourceInstance` and `b:SubResourceInstance` get updated, but not in `b:ValueInstance`.

So, to conclude: SPARQL and Fuseki do exactly what they should... so the initial problem seems to have to do with my real data (or my lack of understanding of my data).

Comment: I don't think you're doing anything wrong, `USING` should create the dataset default graph similar to `FROM`in a `SELECT` query. Might be something in your Fuseki setup, Andy will probably answer here soon. Nevertheless, did you try to put the triple pattern with the `subClassOf` property path into a graph pattern explicitly?

Comment: Thanks! I'm not 100% sure what you mean by that or how I would do it, so most likely not, I'm afraid. If you provide me with a snippet so I get the gist of what I should do, I'd be happy to try it

Comment: oh sorry, I meant to explicitly define the graph in the `WHERE` part for that data, i.e. `GRAPH <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base> { ?def <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf>* <http://www.knora.org/ontology/knora-base#Resource> .}`

Comment: Which version of Fuseki are you running? And could you produce a small complete illustration?

Comment: @AndyS I'm running Fuseki 4.4.0 - will have to see how easily I can produce a complete illustration (as this is part of a bigger system... but I'll give it a try)

Comment: @UninformedUser I tried that just now (see my update to the post), but it didn't change anything. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @AndyS I could not reproduce the issue with a simple example (see my update to the post), so the problem seems to be me not understanding my own data, I suppose. =/